# JQuery select by content

Tags: jquery

The next selector is not working? What's wrong with this?

Javascript:

```
$('.detWindow').children("tr:contains('Mary'),tr:contains('John')").addClass('highlight');
```

HTML:

```
<div class='detWindow'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Another</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td>Another</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Another</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `tr` are not the children of `div` so instead of [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) need to use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find an descendant in >1 level

```
$('.detWindow').find("tr:contains('Mary'),tr:contains('John')").addClass('highlight');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LERMn/)

Comment: I thought all elements inside another was its children. Thank you.